# Using Subdomains for Multilingual website

Tags: localization, web, subdomain

I have recently decided to choose the *subdomains* option to redirect users to their *preferred language*.

for example if I have a *french user hitting my website*, the user will be automatically *redirected to fr.example.com*

The original language is English(US), and I have only a landing page to be translated in other languages (Not All website).

The landing page is index.php for example.

Do I have to duplicate the css files and the index.php in subdomains too ?

or

Is there any other options ?

Comment: Hi David, welcome to stackOverflow! I think your question is too broad. Of course, there's other options (I bet you can think of some), but going through all hypothetical options can't possible work -- it would take infinite memory ;) Generally, it's better to reduce the scope of your question and ask something more clear and precisely answerable.

Comment: I'm not using a database for translations, but i need to understand how can i redirect the user to a subdomain (Same Design but different language), and there is no duplication ?

Comment: There's really just too many ways of doing this, your question is too broad if you don't even start to define what framework you'll be working on, what you mean with "shared" etc. I'll try to come up with an analogy: You ask "I want to write a book with many chapters. How can I do that?" and my reply is: well, that is kind of a big question that can't be answered without knowing very much about what book you want to write, and what kind of author you are.

Comment: Why will the framework matter to what I'm asking ?
My question is, I have: index.php to be translated to many different languages, i chose the subdomain option to redirect users to their preferred language. how can i accomplish this without duplicating index.php in subdomains ?

Comment: Yes, it matters. Wouldn't I stress it otherwise? Most CMS do have things like management for multiple languages of the same content, and of course that's important. You're ever so hesitant to help us answer your questions, so I'll stop replying you here, as I find it mildly frustrating.

Comment: I'm not using CMS or even drag&drop websites, I'm using PHP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I am mistaken, I guess you want to redirect users to their preferred language using PHP framework, but i would advise you to use `.htaccess` file to do this.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} (fr) [NC]
RewriteRule .* http://fr.example.com/ [R,L]
```

Note: you have to change example.com to your own domain name. I used the `fr` language as an example.